# Given a RuntimeId from UISpy and Process Memory Dump, how do I find the cause of a hidden UI element?

Tags: windbg, microsoft-ui-automation

Occasionally an application bug generates a hidden UI control with Z-Index which means it sits above other UI elements. This hidden pane appears in the top-left corner of the screen and stops users from loading the 'File' menu from any maximised windows. If the application is closed, the UI element disappears.

Using UISpy, I was able to capture the following information about the element:

```
AutomationElement
  General Accessibility
    AccessKey:     ""
    AcceleratorKey:            ""
    IsKeyboardFocusable:               "True"
    LabeledBy:      "(null)"
    HelpText:        ""

  State
    IsEnabled:       "True"
    HasKeyboardFocus:    "False"

  Identification
    ClassName:    "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.365bd83"
    ControlType:  "ControlType.Pane"
    Culture:            "(null)"
    AutomationId:              ""
    LocalizedControlType:               "pane"
    Name:              ""
    ProcessId:       "10968 (MyApplication)"
    RuntimeId:     "42 21628486"
    IsPassword:    "False"
    IsControlElement:       "True"
    IsContentElement:      "True"

  Visibility
    BoundingRectangle:   "(0, 0, 132, 38)"
    ClickablePoint:              "(null)"
    IsOffscreen:   "False"

ControlPatterns
```

I also have a memory dump of the application open in WinDbg. How do I find the managed object that refers to the UI element with RuntimeID `"42 21628486"`? Or perhaps I can do a search for objects with a specific width?

I'm hoping that, by finding the managed object, it will give some clues as to the cause of the hidden window.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't figured out if it's possible using WinDbg but was able to attached an instance of Visual Studio and...

Using `Inspect.exe` was able to find a hwnd (which might be the same as the RuntimeId but not sure):

```
How found:  Focus [o:0xFFFFFFFC,c:0x0]
    hwnd=0x0006219E 32bit class="WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.27e1210" style=0x96010000 ex=0x90088
```

Triggered a breakpoint and was able to find the control using the following in the Immediate Window:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(new IntPtr(401822))
```